# ¿Por qué al enviar dos correos adjuntos usando la libreria smtplib solo llega un adjunto?

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib

Al enviar dos archivos adjuntos solo llega un adjunto en gmail pero en outlook recibo los dos.Estoy usando la libreria smtplib y servidor de correos SMT2GO de pago.

Este es el codigo fuente estoy utilizando python 3.9.15

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from loguru import logger
import json
import smtplib

def handle_message_parameters(attachments, cc, to, bcc):
    if attachments is None:
        attachments = []
    if cc is None:
        cc = []
    if not isinstance(attachments, list):
        attachments = str(attachments).split(",")
    if not isinstance(cc, list):
        cc = str(cc).split(",")
    if not isinstance(to, list):
        to = str(to).split(",")
    if not isinstance(bcc, list):
        bcc = str(bcc).split(",")
    return attachments, cc, to, bcc


def send_email_smtp(login, password, server, port, sender, to, cc, bcc, subject, body, attachment):
    attachment, cc, to, bcc = handle_message_parameters(attachment, cc, to, bcc)
    logger.info("subject:    {}".format(subject))
    logger.info("attachment: {}".format(attachment))
    logger.info("to:  {}".format(to))
    logger.info("cc:  {}".format(cc))
    message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    message["Subject"] = "{}".format(subject)
    message["From"] = sender
    message["To"] = ", ".join(to)
    message["Bcc"] = ", ".join(bcc)
    part1 = MIMEText(body, "html")
    if cc:
        message["Cc"] = ", ".join(cc)
        toaddrs = to + cc + bcc
    else:
        toaddrs = to
    logger.info("toaddrs: {}".format(toaddrs))
    message.attach(part1)

    for i in attachment:
        name_file = i.split("/").pop()
        att2 = MIMEText(open(i, 'rb').read(), 'base64', 'gb2312')
        att2["Content-Type"] = 'application/octet-stream'
        att2["Content-Disposition"] = f'attachment; filename={name_file}'
        message.attach(att2)

    try:
        mail = None
        logger.info("server connect:  {}".format(server))
        mail = smtplib.SMTP(server, int(port))
        mail.login(login, password)
        mail.sendmail(sender, toaddrs, message.as_string())
        logger.info("close connect!!")
        return json.dumps({"success": True, "message": "Operación exitosa!!"})
    except Exception as e:
        logger.info("Error type:   {}".format(e))
        return json.dumps({"success": False, "message": str(e)})
    finally:
        if mail != None:
          mail.close()
```

al ejecutar la función send_email_smtp no devuelve ninguna excepción

he probado con varios correos con extension gmail y con todos obtengo como resultado que solo se ha adjuntado uno de ellos.

Los pesos de los archivos son los siguientes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este el resultado esperado que se desea.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de hacer pruebas me di cuenta de que la clave era el peso de los archivos ya que uno de ellos es de OKb y según donde se mande el correo se comporta de manera distinta.

- Para el caso de GMAIL al no tener peso no lo sube (por esta razón solo me llegaba un correo adjunto y no dos)
- Para el caso de Outlook si el archivo no tiene peso de igual manera lo sube curiosamente con peso de 416 bytes. como muesto en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto queda cerrada la pregunta ya que como menciono se debe a un distinto comportamiento entre GMAIL y OUTLOOK al adjuntar archivos adjuntos.